# Use verbs with functions, nouns with classes - what about interfaces?

Tags: object-oriented

Ok, I understand the normal conventions of using verbs with functions and nouns with classes. What about interfaces? Is there any methodology when coming up with interface names that may not be that obvious?

Just to make it clear, I'm not talking about whether to put an "I" in front of the name or if to use camelCase or PascalCase. I'm wondering about the method of figuring out a clear, semantic name for an interface.

**EDIT**
I'm obsessing on how to name an interface in the clearest way. I guess it just needs to be a noun too because when I think of naming classes I think of the closest "real" world object it can relate to. I suppose real world interfaces are things like a keyboard, mouse, remote control, ATM screen. Those are all nouns. Anyhow, any additional insight on a good way to formulate interface names would be appreciated.

Comment: Hm..  Based on the title, I thought this was going to be about equating parts of speech between programming and English.  In which case, [madlibs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_Libs#Format) seem possible.

Comment: Remember, when you create a class, you are also creating an interface for objects instantiated by that class... Or to put it another way, classes are *realized* interfaces. So, they should use the same naming convention.

Comment: Also, IMHO the "use verbs with functions" is too general. You should use verbs with *commands* and nouns with *queries*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'd say it depends on what the interface defines. In some cases when the interface is rather specific and detailed, I think a noun is best. Examples are `IList`, `ICollection`.

Sometimes though an interface is more about adding certain general features to a class. In that case I think an *adjective* is best. Examples are `IDisposable`, `IEnumerable`, ...

Maybe another way to think about this is how many "abilities" your interface defines.

For example, the `IList<T>` interface defines these abilities: Add, Clear, Contains, Insert, Remove, ... These are all properties of a list so `IList` is a good name.

`IDisposable` on the other hand only defines one ability: Dispose. So it is suited for anything that is disposable. Hence the name `IDisposable`.

Comment: I'd suggest using an "_able" adjective if your interface would be be named after things that can be done to your object (e.g. `IEnumerable`), a "_er" noun if your interface would be named after things your object does to other objects (e.g. `IEqualityComparer`), and a general noun if your interface is named after a type of thing whose behavior it mimics (e.g. `IList<T>`).

Comment: Comment by @supercat should really be included in this answer. It makes lot of sense.

Comment: Actually prefixing the interface name with `I` is redundant.

Answer (score 6):

An **interface** describes behavior so the names should say so. I am not sure about a rule for this but you will know the name when you hear it.

Some examples:

```
Flyable      - Can Fly
Workable     - Can work
Negotiatable - Can negotiate.
```

I think it is not proper to name interfaces with `I` and call `Set` with `ISet` because, as a developer, you should not be worried whether it is an interface or a class. I see this practice does not exist in Java now.

Comment: +1 for "as a developer you should not be worried wheter iti s an interface or a class."

Comment: "as a developer you should not be worried whether it is an interface or a class" - disagree because if it is an interface then you need to know which members you should implement.

Comment: @MaximusMinimus prefixing it with `I` is redundant regardless. Then why not prefix abstract classes with `A`, regular classes with `C` etc??

Comment: @user1870400 - true, but that's not the part I'm disagreeing with.

Answer (score 4):

Since an interface is really just an expression of the "what" but not "how" of a type, I would name them in the same way that you name classes, at least from a parts of speech perspective.  The only thing I might add to this is that they're often going to be more general than the specific implementers (e.g. "Customer" interface may have "ProspectiveCustomer" and "PayingCustomer" implementers).

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Answer:** Interface is more about addition of a **SET** of abilities, features, common boundaries or interconnections between entities, classes, models, concepts, etc..

Thing about adding common behavior to classes and entities, and then a good meaningful name will come up to identify the set of realted features.

Interface Naming like : `IStateMachineBuilder, IUserContextProviderBuilder, IEntityBuilderBuilder, IActiveAware, etc.` probably explain the concept.

Comment: Yes, interfaces represent contracts, or capabilities; so much is well known. But how does this answer the question of how to name them? All you're really saying in that regard is, "Think about it, and inspiration will strike you." This does not give any recommendation, for instance, which of the following names should be chosen, any why: `IStateMachineBuilder` (noun), `IBuildStateMachine` (named after an action), `ICanBuildStateMachine` (named after a capability), etc.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is used like a class. Therefore, it should also be named with a noun when you name classes with nouns. Prefer abstract nouns, for example "Vehicle" when the classes are "Car" and "Truck".

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if the interface contains only methods it will be good to name it using a verbs like "Actions" where as if it represents a generic class wchich contains static , final fields then we can use a generic Noun just like "Vehicle"